# graph object update_xaxes not updating

Tags: python, object, graph, plotly, subplot

I have this simple code:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

surf=make_subplots(
    rows=1,
    cols=2,
    subplot_titles=(
        'Surface growing for {} seconds'.format(stop),
        'Surface growing for {} seconds'.format(stop)
        ),
    horizontal_spacing=0.1,
    specs=[[{"type": "scene"},{"type": "scene"}]]
)
surf.update_layout(
    template='plotly_dark',
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            font=dict(
                family='Open Sans',
                size=15,
                color='black'
            ),
            bgcolor='gray',
            bordercolor='white',
            borderwidth=3,
            type='buttons',
            buttons=[
                dict(
                    label='Play',
                    method='animate',
                    args=[None]
                )
            ]
        )
    ],
    width=1200,
    height=900
)
surf.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(
        showlegend=False,mode='markers',x=[0],y=[0],z=[0],marker_size=9
    ),1,1
)
surf.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(
        showlegend=False,mode='markers',x=[0],y=[0],z=[0],marker_size=9
    ),1,2
)
surf.update_xaxes(title='X Real',row=1,col=1)
pio.show(surf)
```

But the title for X Axis is not updating as you can see in attached pic:
[image]
I have seen in plotly community that the instruction: `surf.update_xaxes(title='X Real',row=1,col=1)` is a valid solution to this issue of updating axis properties in plotly subplots, but for me is not working for some reason I can't identify. Could anyone help me telling me what I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: `stop` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you should use a different way to update layout. I added an example for the second subplot too.

```py
surf.update_layout(scene=dict(xaxis_title='X Real'),
                   scene2=dict(xaxis_title='X Fake'))
```

Where `scene` is the layout for the first subplot while `scene2` is the layout for the second one.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it solved the issue.